# Link "editar tags" inacessível

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Ao tentar editar as tags desta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205977/2541) verifiquei que o link "editar tags", ao ser colocado na linha seguinte, fica inacessível.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pra mim aparece somente o link `editar` e por lá eu edito as tags. Talvez pela minha reputação.

Comment: @acklay o problema é que o ismael editou e não se pode ver mais a falha, era um possivel problema com layout ou com limite de tags, mas creio que o erro exista sim, vou adicionar as tags novamente para testar.

Comment: Ramaral pode ser um problema no layout, informe o navegador e versão, mas antes disto tente limpar o cache. Nota: uso Opera e Chrome e parecem normais.

Comment: Outro detalhe importante, as vezes após editar uma pergunta aparece um "box" com o nome da pessoa que editou, talvez isso tenha feito o bug não ocorrer mais, poderia confirmar se após a minha edição o bug ainda ocorre?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento O "bug" já não ocorre mais. Uso o Firefox 53.0.2.

Comment: Devem ter notado rapidamente a falha e já corrigiram.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ou é devido à "box" com o nome da pessoa que editou.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Deve ter sido uma situação muito particular. Já editei muitas perguntas com várias tags e nunca me deparei com esse problema.

Comment: @ramaral ok, vamos deixar em aberto, pode ter sido qualquer tag HTML (com algum CSS) que afetou, pode realmente ser algo muito especifico. Se notar novamente é só chamar (ou editar com detalhes para levar ao topo).

Comment: @WendelRodrigues Sim. A edição rápida de tags é só pra usuários com mais de 10k de reputação.

Comment: Isso depende do tamanho do monitor ou da janela do navegador? Porque nunca vi formar 2 linhas de tags aqui.

Comment: @diegofm Não sei. Como já disse num comentário anterior nunca tal me tinha acontecido e as tentativas do Guilherme para o replicar foram infrutíferas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aconteceu comigo - exatamente como descrito pelo @ramaral - no Opera, também. Mas, assim como com todos vocês, o problema não existe mais e não consigo mais replicá-lo no nosso ambiente de "teste" interno.

Meu palpite, como foi sugerido, é que alguém não verificou tudo antes de dar commit

Mas já foi corrigido